# spanning-tree port type edge trunk on port-channel vs physical interface

Tags: cisco, switch, spanning-tree, trunk, port-channel

If i configure `spanning-tree port type edge trunk` on physical interface instead of port-channel does that work?

Or i have to do `spanning-tree port type edge trunk` on port-channel ?

Example:

```
interface Ethernet1/33
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,100
  spanning-tree port type edge trunk
  spanning-tree bpduguard enable
  speed 10000
  channel-group 133 mode active
```

Port-channel

```
interface port-channel133
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30,100
  speed 10000
  vpc 133
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strongly suggested: Configure both port-channel and its members identically (except of course for `description` and the `channel-group` and `vpc` bits).

As long as an interface is not configured to be member of a LAG, or because LACP negotiation failed and the interface remains *LACP individual* [1], the configuration from the given (physical) interface applies, and "switching" (as in "MAC address learning" and forwarding of frames) and spanning-tree behaviour happens in the context of the (physical) interface. `show mac address-table ...` will show that MAC addresses are not learned on the port-channel interface, but on the physical interface, and `show spanning tree vlan XXX` will show the physical interface as active interface (in the STP state and role it will happen to have).

Once the interface is integrated into a port-channel interface, all the "Layer2 things" (MAC address learning, spanning-tree) are handled in the context of the  port-channel interface, and the command outputs change: MAC addresses are learned on the port-channel interface, and the port-channel appears as active interface in the spanning tree(s).

Also: Having portfast (`port type edge [trunk]`) on a member interface but not on the port-channel interface will result in the dreaded 30seconds of LIS/LRN (for STP) or LRN (for RSTP and RPVST+), before the port-channel interface goes into FWD mode and allows traffic in/out.

Plus, when a non-portfast port (regardless if individual or port-channel) goes "FWD", a spanning-tree topology change notification runs through the pertaining spanning tree(s).

**Addon:**
Nexus 3K and 9K switches have a convenient feature to help integrating physical ports into port-channels:

1. configure the port-channel interface with all details as needed and intended.
2. on the member interfaces, use the `force` keyword when applying the port-channel configuration: `channel-group NN force mode active`. This will overwrite any possibly conflicting configuration of the physical interface, and enforce the config as given on the `port-channel NN` interface.

---

[1] and the interface was not suspended because of "lacp suspend-individual" (default on some Nexus switches), which would bring the interface down.